# Python show button only if there is data in the database column

Tags: html, python-3.x, postgresql

The python application receives data from the postgres database and displays it on an html page. It is necessary to make a button by clicking on which a file containing the contents of one of the database columns will be downloaded, but only if the data is in the database. I made the button itself and downloading to a file, but I don’t understand how to configure the display of this button only if there is data in the desired column.

```
SELECT c.id, c."name", c."date",  c.description, EXTRACT('Day' FROM (date::DATE) - now()), cert_obj  FROM certificate c
```

It is necessary to display the button only if cert_obj is not None.

Button code:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Download" name="change" >
```

I just started learning python and flask and would like to implement this task without using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with Jinja in Python, it allows to write/embed python code in html.

```
  {% if xyz is not None %}
     //Your HTML code to render conditionally.
  {% endif %}
```

Dont forget to replace "xyz" with your desired variable.
More [here](https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-2-loops-and-conditionals/#compare).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Only None in lower case.
https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/520